# How to filter out ULID on oklog JSON messages

Tags: logging

I am after a tip on how best to filter out ULID on [oklog](https://github.com/oklog) messages. Ideally i'd like to do it directly from query command line without piping through another program, but don't think this is possible?

Given this query:

./oklog query -from 1h

> {"cluster_host_id": "awx",
>   "level": "INFO", "@timestamp": "2018-04-07T21:19:43.362Z", "host":
>   "awxweb", "logger_name": "awx.api.generics", "message": "User admin
>   logged out.", "type": "other"}01CAH1XHTT8PMC1T98C2S00ZD2
>   {"cluster_host_id": "awx", "level": "INFO", "@timestamp":
>   "2018-04-07T21:59:08.312Z", "host": "awxweb", "logger_name":
>   "awx.api.generics", "message": "User admin logged in.", "type":
>   "other"}01CAH1XQN41EAR570FHGAPA34J ...

I can not pipe above into *jq*, eg

./oklog query -from 1h **| jq '.'**

because of the ULIDS

Answer (score 0):

FYI this is what I did; run oklog through below Python and jq can then correctly display the json output:

> import re
>
> stdin = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
>
> [print('{%s}'%j) for j in re.findall('{(.*?)}',stdin,re.S)]